# Cut command ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, cut

## ///**How to cut:**

```
"Good_1612
Notsogood_man_1683_volt_2947"
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8.1.109.3.1.2.4.114.111.111.116
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8.1.110.3.1.2.4.114.111.111.116
STRING:
```

**with the output:**

```
Good_1612
Notsogood_man_1683_volt_2947
```

Answer (score 1):

`cut` is for cutting out vertical columns. You can use `head` (or `tail`) if you want to cut out rows. In your case, assuming this string is in a file called `data.txt`, `head -2 data.txt` should g ive you what you want. You can then pipe it through `sed s/\"//g` to get rid of the quotes assuming  they're literally in the file.

Comment: Thnaks! This helps me a lot. Kudos!

Comment: You're welcome. You should mark the answer as accepted so that if someone else comes by here, they'll get it.